# How to remove the unnecessary information and restructure this associative array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have this php associative array which I created from a MySQL query. It looks like this;

```
        array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                        'items' => array(
                                'index_no' => '1'
                        ),
                        (int) 0 => array(
                                'NumItems' => '2'
                        )
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                        'items' => array(
                                'index_no' => '2'
                        ),
                        (int) 0 => array(
                                'NumItems' => '3'
                        )
                )
```

It looks unnecessarily complicated. I would like to simplify it to look something like this;

```
        array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                                'index_no' => '1',
                                'NumItems' => '2'
                        )
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                                'index_no' => '2',
                                'NumItems' => '3'
                        )
                )
```

How can this be done in php? I have been stuck on this problem for some time. I will post my answer if I have it. I would appreciate it if someone could give me some starting point. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
$tempArray = array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                        'items' => array(
                                'index_no' => '1'
                        ),
                        (int) 0 => array(
                                'NumItems' => '2'
                        )
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                        'items' => array(
                                'index_no' => '2'
                        ),
                        (int) 0 => array(
                                'NumItems' => '3'
                        )
                ));

$newArray = array();
$i=0;
foreach($tempArray as $temp) {
    $newArray[$i]['index_no'] = $temp['items']['index_no'];
    $newArray[$i]['NumItems'] = $temp[0]['NumItems'];
    $i++;
}
print "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php $res=array(array('item'=>1,'number'=>5),array('item'=>2,'number'=>56));
 $final_array =array();
 $i=0;
  foreach ($res as $val)
  {
     foreach($val as $key=>$val2)
     {
      $final_array[$i][$key] = $val2;

      }$i++;
    }

  print_r($final_array);
   ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for you.

```
$diffArray = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'items' => array(
            'index_no' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'NumItems' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'items' => array(
            'index_no' => '2'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'NumItems' => '3'
        )
        ));

print_r($diffArray);

$getArray = array();
foreach ($diffArray as $simArray) {

    $getArray['index_no'][] = $simArray['items']['index_no'];
    $getArray['NumItems'][]= $simArray[0]['NumItems'];
}
print_r($getArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $items) {
    $temp = array('index_no' => $items['index_no']);
    $temp = array_merge($temp, $items[0]);
    $newArray[] = $temp;
}
```

it will add all the keys to the array under `index - 0`